# Get all Secrets from Kubernetes on a Pod

Tags: kubernetes

First of all, I have read the documentation and i see this text, which is pretty self explanatory, `To use a secret, a pod needs to reference the secret.` But I want to see if its possible to get all secrets from a secret definition without defining each one of them in a pod, what i mean is this.

This is what I have

```
        env:
            - name: MY_FRST_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secret
                  key: MY_FRST_SECRET
            - name: MY_SECOND_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secret
                  key: MY_SECOND_SECRET
```

This is what I want

```
        env:
            - name: *
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secret
                  key: *
```

I know this seems silly, but what i mean is that i want to see if there is a way to grab all the variables inside the secret, and import them with the same name as the variable is defined. so it will be

```
VarName = SecretName
VarValue = SecretValue
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I turns out i can achieve this but with config maps, here is the documentation link on how to do it https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables

if the URL changes in the future, here is the code for reference

```
apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: dapi-test-pod
   spec:
     containers:
       - name: test-container
         image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
         command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
         envFrom:
         - configMapRef:
             name: special-config
     restartPolicy: Never
```